# Does dialog exist for BB-8?

Tags: star-wars, droids, bb-8

BB-8 seems to have a sense of humour and have a cheeky/nasty side to him but is there a full list of what he is meant to be saying (not just fanboy hopeful assumptions)?

As there is dialog for Chewie and other characters who speak other languages but does any exist for this droid in particular?

Comment: *Rey knelt beside the mysterious droid. “Where’d you come from?”
He beeped an answer.
“Oh, classified? Really,” Rey said incredulously. “Well, me too. Big secret.”*

Comment: @Valorum - have edited. Re quote, doesn't offer actual dialog by BB8 though.

Comment: The dupe does though - *"In the script its all "BB-8 Beeps excitedly" and "BB-8 Bleeps mournfully", and so on."*

Comment: Same as R2 in script, what I mean is actual words like Chewies 'that old mans mad' etc

Comment: Nope. Not that I've seen